# Using jQuery to send form data with array of form elements with the same name

Tags: forms, jquery, serialization

I have this form:

```
...
        <td><input type="text" name="code[]" value="" /></td>
        <td>
              <select class="selectProductOrders" name="selectProductOrders[]">
                  <option value="default" disabled selected>Select a product</option> 
              </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="rsp[]" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="trade[]" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="discount[]" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="qty[]" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="cost[]" value="" /></td>
...
```

There is more above and below it but this is the important part. This row in a table is repeated depending on how many products are in the order, so I thought it would be easier to parse arrays of each order item element on the server side. And because the form is quite large I have decided to use `jQuery.serialize()` to  send the data in json format.

It sends the rest of the form ok, but doesnt send over arrays of each input element stated above, it just sends the last row.

Any idea of a solution to this? I suppose I could just type the values out form the form manually into a json format but I wanted to get my head round the serialize problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't use `jQuery.serialize()` if the inputs have all the same name.

To send an array to the server I would recommend to number your inputs:

```
<td><input type="text" name="code[0]" value="" /></td>
    <td>
          <select class="selectProductOrders" name="selectProductOrders[0]">
              <option value="default" disabled selected>Select a product</option> 
          </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="rsp[0]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="trade[0]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="discount[0]" value="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="qty[0]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="cost[0]" value="" /></td>


<td><input type="text" name="code[1]" value="" /></td>
    <td>
          <select class="selectProductOrders" name="selectProductOrders[1]">
              <option value="default" disabled selected>Select a product</option> 
          </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="rsp[1]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="trade[1]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="discount[1]" value="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="qty[1]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="cost[1]" value="" /></td>
```

This ensures that all your values are sent to the server.

Comment: Using serialize is OK in this case and you do not have to number the array. The values are properly placed into the serialized string. The trick is getting the data out of the string on the server-side. http://jsfiddle.net/2DEK2/